# WPF datagrid not showing data

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a datagrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="messageGrid">           
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Revision" Binding="{Binding Message.Revision}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Opcode" Binding="{Binding Message.Opcode}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Reason" Binding="{Binding Message.Reason}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Reaction" Binding="{Binding Message.Reaction}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Projects" Binding="{Binding Message.Projects}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Links" Binding="{Binding Message.Links}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Notes" Binding="{Binding Message.Notes}"></DataGridTextColumn>       
    </DataGrid>
```

On the preview I don't see the columns that I wanted to see (Revision, Opcode, etc.) and when I run the program i don't have any columns or data inside, why is that happening?

P.s 
I have data inside Message.Revision and so on i checked that

**EDIT**:

the view model where i have the Message property that i use as items source:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using YogevAfekaRAPAT.YNIDS.Helpers;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data;

namespace YogevAfekaRAPAT.YNIDS.ViewModels
{
public class MessageDetailsViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    #region Private Data Members


    private Model.Message message;


    private ObservableCollection<Model.MType> types;

    //private FileManager.fileManager fileManager;

    private Logger.Logger logger;
    #endregion


    #region Properties

    #region Types
    private ObservableCollection<Model.MType> _types;
    public ObservableCollection<Model.MType> Types
    {
        get { return _types; }
        set
        {
            if (_types != value)
            {
                _types = value;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Message

    public Model.Message Message
    {
        get
        {
            return message;
        }
        set
        {
            if (message == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            message = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Message);
        }
    }
    #endregion


    #endregion


    #region Ctor
    public MessageDetailsViewModel(Model.Network network, String messageName)
    {
        fileManager = FileManager.fileManager.getFileManager();
        //Message = network
        Message = network.getMessageFromName(messageName);
        Debug.WriteLine("Inside: public MessageDetailsViewModel(Model.Network network, String messageName) messageName = " + messageName + " Message.Desc = " + Message.Opcode);

    }
    #endregion

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to enclose your columns definitions inside `<DataGrid.Columns>`:

```
<DataGrid Name="messageGrid">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Revision" Binding="{Binding Message.Revision}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Opcode" Binding="{Binding Message.Opcode}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Reason" Binding="{Binding Message.Reason}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Reaction" Binding="{Binding Message.Reaction}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Projects" Binding="{Binding Message.Projects}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Links" Binding="{Binding Message.Links}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Notes" Binding="{Binding Message.Notes}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

You need to bind to a collection. Try defining an `ObservableCollection` that returns just `Message`.

```
public ObservableCollection<Model.Message> Messages
{
    get { return new ObservableCollection<Model.Message> { Message }; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that actually made the columns to appear but the data inside is still not. Do you have an idea what that might be?

Comment: It is already set to false, the problem was that i forgot the item source. but now i have rows without data

Comment: My item source is from type Message which is a class in my model.
It just have the headers (That i hard coded) but no data

Comment: But I don't have a list of Messages. or should i have a list with one item?
I checked it, I can't have a list of message. It is just not right for me, do you have maybe other suggestions?

Comment: I checked it, I can't have a list of message. It is just not right for me, do you have maybe other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add **`Columns`** under **`<DataGrid.Columns>`** tag.

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
     .... // Add columns here.
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you, that actually made the columns to appear but the data inside is still not. Do you have an idea what that might be?

Comment: You have to set `ItemsSource` on dataGrid to get the rows.

Comment: Ok that made some rows, but without data. My item source is Message (an object) and on each row i wrote for example:   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Opcode" Binding="{Binding Opcode}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>  where Opcode is a property inside message. 
And i don't have any data inside.

Sorry for all the beginners questions my wfp skills are very low

Comment: Class which is set as ItemsSource and collection where you have set ItemsSource.