# C# WPF datagrid not showing anything

Tags: c#, wpf, list, datagrid

I am new to WPF. I presume my problem is different from

[c# wpf datagrid not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395464/c-sharp-wpf-datagrid-not-showing)

[WPF datagrid not showing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23311296/wpf-datagrid-not-showing-data)

[Datagrid not showing data in wpf with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194747/datagrid-not-showing-data-in-wpf-with-c-sharp)

so this should be very simple. 
I have a datagrid binded to a class which is:

```
public class PcDmisData
{
    ...     

    [Serializable]
    public class MyImage
    {
        public object Image;
        public bool IsImageEmbedded;
    }


    [Serializable]
    public class MySoundFile
    {
        public object SoundFile;
        public bool IsSoundEmbedded;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class PartProgram
    {
        public PartProgram()
        {
            ProgramTracefields = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            ProgramTracefields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("FIELD1", "Batch"));
            ProgramTracefields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("FIELD2", "S/N"));
            ProgramTracefields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("FIELD3", "Operator"));
        }

        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; } 
        public string PartProgramFilename { get; set; }
        public List<MyImage> LsImagepath { get; set; }  
        public MySoundFile SoundFile { get; set;}
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
        public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ProgramTracefields { get; set; }   //optional
    }

    ....
```

the xaml concerning the datagrid is:

```
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgPartProgram" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                    CanUserResizeColumns="True"  GridLinesVisibility="All" FontSize="12"
                    Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="5"
                    AutoGeneratingColumn="Datagrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"
                    Height="283" Margin="0,0,-0.4,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I change the header of the columns through:

```
private void Datagrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    String strDatagridName = (sender as DataGrid).Name;
    switch (strDatagridName.ToUpper())
    {
        case "DGPARTPROGRAM":
            switch (e.PropertyName.ToUpper())
            {
                case "DESCRIPTION":
                    e.Column.Header = Langs.Word(Langs.eWords.Description);
                    break;
                case "NOTE":
                    e.Column.Header = Langs.Word(Langs.eWords.Notes);
                    break;
                case "PARTPROGRAMFILENAME":
                    e.Column.Header = Langs.Word(Langs.eWords.PPfilename);
                    break;
                case "LSIMAGEPATH":
                    e.Column.Header = Langs.Word(Langs.eWords.ImageFilename);
                    break;
                case "SOUNDFILE":
                    e.Column.Header = Langs.Word(Langs.eWords.SoundFilename);
                    break;
                case "BARCODE":
                    e.Column.Header = Langs.Word(Langs.eWords.Barcode);
                    break;
                case "PROGRAMTRACEFIELDS":
                    e.Column.Header = Langs.Word(Langs.eWords.ProgramTracefields);
                    break;
                default:
                    e.Column.Header = e.PropertyName;
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

The binding is:

```
dgPartProgram.ItemsSource = EasyRunData.lstPartPrograms;
```

and then I add elements to the list through:

```
var newPp = new PcDmisData.PartProgram()
{
    Description = nppw.tbDescription.Text,
    Note = nppw.tbNote.Text,
    PartProgramFilename = nppw.tbFilename.Text,
};
EasyRunData.lstPartPrograms.Add(newPp);
```

not all the elements are set but the shouldn't be a problem in my book.

So from the image you can see that the columns are correctly set but no element appears
[image]

thanx for any help
Patrick

**ADD** I have taken (and modified to be similar to my problem) this class from the tutorial

```
public partial class SimpleDataGridSample : Window
    {
            TheClass tc = new TheClass();

            public SimpleDataGridSample()
            {
                    InitializeComponent();

                    tc.users1 = new List<User>();
                    tc.users1.Add(new User() { Id = 1, Name = "A", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 23) });
                    tc.users1.Add(new User() { Id = 2, Name = "B", Birthday = new DateTime(1974, 1, 17) });
                    tc.users1.Add(new User() { Id = 3, Name = "C", Birthday = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2) });

                    tc.users2 = new List<User>();
                    tc.users2.Add(new User() { Id = 4, Name = "D", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 23) });
                    tc.users2.Add(new User() { Id = 5, Name = "E", Birthday = new DateTime(1974, 1, 17) });
                    tc.users2.Add(new User() { Id = 6, Name = "F", Birthday = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2) });


            }



            private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                    dgSimple.ItemsSource = tc.users1;
            }

            private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                    dgSimple.ItemsSource = tc.users2;
            }
    }

    public class TheClass
    {
            public List<User> users1, users2;
    }

    public class User
    {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }

            public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    }
```

}

So in short:
1. the datagrid is created
2. the datagrid is AFTERWARDS binded to source 1
3. the datagrid is AFTER AFTERWARD binded to source 2

Comment: what type is your `EasyRunData.lstPartPrograms` ?

Comment: @kirotab it's `public List<PcDmisData.PartProgram> lstPartPrograms = new List<PcDmisData.PartProgram>();`

Comment: Ah ok, so you'll need to either implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, a lot of info about this, and then when you add your items just set the list or raise this event (it will notify the view that you have changed the data through your binding)... Or you could add the data beforehand and then set the items source... or you could use `ObservableCollection<PcDmisData.PartProgram>` which will update your view even when you add separate items in the list

Comment: Easiest to test for now would be to use Observable collection I think. When you get more info on the subject you can change it depending on your application needs.

Comment: @kirotab: thanks for the hint, I'll implement it right now and let you know. I based my code on what's written here [link](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/custom-columns/). And here it just adds a simple datagrid: **<DataGrid Name="dgSimple"></DataGrid>** and then binds it through **dgSimple.ItemsSource = users;** with List<User> **users = new List<User>();** and that is enough. By adding elements users.Add(new User() { ... }); the datagrid is updated. So why having to use  NotifyPropertyChanged interface or ObservableCollection<PcDmisData.PartProgram>???

Comment: sorry the right url above is http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/introduction/

Comment: @kirotab I just swapped list with ObservableCollection and that worked!!!!

Comment: Hi @Patrick, the difference in the example is visible right away however considering I'm dealing with similar issue in our project at the moment maybe it's not that obvious for newer people to WPF and it's binding concepts. In the example they are creating the list and adding the items before they set the `ItemsSource`, so in their case if you add more items it will simply not update the view also. As I mentioned previously you have to tell the view that there is change or to use a collection that is already doing that (there are more observable data structures). There are gotchas using them

Comment: I will try to add a structured answer but I'm pretty busy lately so not going to be right away, check my previous comment on the reason why it seems like it is working differently in the example. Also be careful using the observable collections as you would with normal may cause issues, for example when you want to change the whole collection content you can't just change the reference, you have to `.Clear()` the items and then add them to your exisiting collection.

Comment: @kirotab. So first of all thanx for saving me!!!! Then you might want to see my latest ADD. And last but not least you might you could add an answer so that I can vote you!! That works so I'll appreciate your answer even if it comes at a later time when you are freer